# How can I insert multiple rows in MySQL after selection them in trigger

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, insert

I am adding new user to database `user_data`. My trigger has to store id of semester (from insert query) on high school and then select from another database list of subjects, which are taught this semester.
At the end it has to insert into grades table rows which constains id of user, id of semester, and id of subject. I want to add that there are multiple subjects in semester.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `data_shipment_extras_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE semester_id DATETIME;

        SELECT
            semester_id
        INTO @semester_id
        FROM other_database.subjects s
        WHERE s.user_id = NEW.id;

        SET NEW.semester_id = @semester_id;
    END
```

Simply modify it a bit for your needs.

Comment: I want to do something a bit diffrent. semester_id is in insert query which release the trigger. Then i need it to select subjects from another table . Subject table contains foreign key which is semester id. So, after query i have few subject id's and then on another table (grades) i have to put rows contains id's of subject, id of semester and id of added user.